# Android long drawable list

Tags: android, loops, android-drawable

I have this list in an android Java file:

```
int[] imagelist = new int[]{R.drawable.n0d,R.drawable.n1d,R.drawable.n2d};
```

How can I make this list longer with a loop? In the end I'd like something like this:

```
int[] imagelist = new int[]{R.drawable.n0d,R.drawable.n1d,...,R.drawable.n85d};
```

Later I'd like to use it in a for loop, to display images in ImageViews:

```
int lenght = 3; //I'd like it to be: int lenght = 85;
for (int i=0;i<lenght;i++){
        imageViews[i] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViews[i].setImageResource(imagelist[i]);
        imageViews[i].setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);
        linearlayout.addView(imageViews[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer..!
I used getIdentifier.

```
for (int i=0;i<lenght;i++){
    imagelist[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("n"+(i)+"d","drawable",getPackageName());
}
```